# My wifi doesn't show up in the Visible Networks 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04

My wifi network doesn't show up in the visible Network list. I am not too far from the router. I have used the same wired connection from the router to install my wifi card drivers, I am using dual boot. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the wireless channel? Can you see other networks?

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: Wireless Chanel is of 2.4GHz. Yes, I can see other networks.